# C# - any way to use _addcarry_u64 intrinsic?

Tags: c#, intrinsics, bigint

I'm trying to prototype an unsigned BigInteger type with fixed byte size. The general idea is to have a struct with a fixed buffer of UInt64 parts.

In order to do addition of those big integers efficiently, I could use a C# equivalent of the [_addcarry_u64](https://scc.ustc.edu.cn/zlsc/tc4600/intel/2015.1.133/compiler_c/GUID-93E27B31-FDA6-4026-A2C4-98BF238349E9.htm) intrinsic function, as supported by MSVC or ICC in the C++ world.
So far, I unfortunately couldn't find a baked-in equivalent in .NET Core 2.1.

Is there any equivalent in the C# world already (maybe with .NET Core 3.0 intrinsics? I can't test that on my machine unfortunately)?

Alternatively, is there any reasonable way for a custom implementation?
The only way I can think of would be to generate Assembly for these instructions, but then again, the only ways I've seen to invoke Assembly at all from C# is via PInvoke, and - to be tested - but I'd strongly suppose the overhead of that will be considerable larger than the performance to be gained from the intrinsic in the first place.

Thanks

Comment: I think it is a great question, but I can't see it under here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Runtime/Intrinsics/ - and you'd *need* this to be implemented by the runtime/JIT - you can't add your own (very easily)

Comment: traditionally libraries like GMP have their lowest-level functions written in asm, separately for each ISA, and with different versions tuned for different x86 CPUs (https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip/mpn/x86_64).  The recent appearance of `_addcarry_u64` would in theory make a higher-level implementation possible, but only if compilers actually made efficient code (this is often not the case for C compilers with `addcarry`: some will usually save the carry flag to an integer register, then rematerialize it back into EFLAGS).  And then there are other operations besides addition.

Comment: Thanks both, bummer - doesn't appear to be immediately useable then in C#! (@PeterCordes absolute in terms of other operations, though for my purpose at the moment, addition is actually the bottleneck)